# Is this red message from Tensorflow an error?

Tags: tensorflow

I have installed CUDA 10.1, cuDNN 7.6, and Tensorflow 2.3.0, and when I execute the code, it shows a message in a red color. I am new to Python, so can you tell me if this is an error or if its just some message?

Here's my code:

```python
import tensorflow as tf

print(tf.__version__)
```

Output - This text showed in red:

```txt
2020-10-10 16:21:02.307068: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll

2.3.1
```

What does that 1st line mean? Have I installed Tensorflow GPU successfully?

Comment: Your code works and the message talks about "Successfully opening" a library... What makes you think you didn't install it correctly? This output is perfectly normal (you'll see a lot more information logs when you run a bit more complex)

Comment: Thank You @GPhilo for answering. I got confuse because I am new to python and that output was in red color. I thought it was some error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"I" comes from "information", so there is no error. The abbreviations are similar to the basic logger from Python.

In your case, it informs you that it successfully opened the cuddn library.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you have installed Tensorflow successfully. The line means that it has successfully opened Cudnn.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily, sometimes, dynamic library gets loaded, but some problem arises, such as - https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/43665.

So try :

```
local_device_protos = device_lib.list_local_devices()
for x in local_device_protos:
    print(x)

with tf.device("/:XLA_GPU:0"):
    do_something()
```

If this gets pass this, well you are on the track.

This is the litmus test for cuda availability in tensorflow :

```
tf.test.is_gpu_available(
    cuda_only=False, min_cuda_compute_capability=None
)
```

ref : https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/test/is_gpu_available